# how do I find out if the update query was successful or not in Cassandra Datastax

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to update a `row`. My code successfully updates the `row` but I found that the `ResultSet` doesn't give me useful information which I could use to conclude whether the update was successful or not.

I am creating the query as follows:

```
QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.set("confirmed",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed))/*(QueryBuilder.set("authprovider",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.loginInfo.providerID)) 
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("id",model.id))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("password",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.password))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("hasher",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.hasher))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("salt",""/*model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.salt.get*/)) 
      .where(QueryBuilder.eq("bucket", id.bucket)) 
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("email", id.email))
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("authprovider", id.authProvider))
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("firstname",id.firstName))
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("lastname",id.lastName))
```

I then use `session.execute`

```
println("update Query: "+updateQuery)
    val resultSet = session.execute(updateQuery)
    println("resultSet from update: "+resultSet)
```

But the `ResultSet` which gets printed is `resultSet from update: ResultSet[ exhausted: true, Columns[]]`. It really doesn't tell me whether the operation was successful or not. How can I find out if the operation was successful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as with INSERT - if you didn't get exception back, the operation is performed, and confirmed with given consistency level (ONE by default).

Comment: but with `insert`, the `ResultSet` seem to contain an `Iterator` but it doesn't seem to be the case with `update` or `delete`

Comment: "INSERT returns no results unless IF NOT EXISTS is used. " -> https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlInsert.html

Comment: bang on Sir! I am using `IfNotExists()` in `insert`