# Document created even after NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, exception, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to execute multiple BatchSatements in parallel with ExecutorService of Java. I want to know whether my query is successfully executed.

I have gone through:
[how do I find out if the update query was successful or not in Cassandra Datastax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388303/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-update-query-was-successful-or-not-in-cassandra-datasta)

It's saying if no exception is there, we can consider it successful. But I am getting  NoHostAvailableException.

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: *********************(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [******************] Timed out waiting for server response))
```

But I can see my data in Cassandra. I want to know how can I know if my document is created successfully in Cassandra. Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batches are different in Cassandra in comparison to the relational databases. And they should be used only in [limited number of the use cases](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html), and they shouldn't be used for batching of inserts/updates to multiple partions, until it's really necessary (see "[misuse of batches](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html)" doc).

Batch will be eventually replayed, even if you got an error back to the driver - this happens because batch is replicated to other nodes before execution.  See [following diagram](https://gist.github.com/alexott/2d5bf95a791450d5dc3e5f5ee11fc94c#gistcomment-3308508) for details.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott for the reply. I think the above flow is for logged batch statements. I am using unlogged batch statements. Is there any way for unlogged batch statements to know, if they are created successfully?

Comment: Logged & unlogged are not necessary correct terms - correct term is single-partition vs multipartition batches.  Are all of your statements against single partition?

Comment: I have both single partition and multi-partition queries. I tried every batch query to be converted to single partition queries but still, there is a use case where I have to use a multi-partition batch query. So what I did, I made batches of queries the bases on size batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb. I am executing those batches in parallel with the help of ExecutorService. But I am not able to find a way to ensure that nothing wrong happened in the batch processing.

Comment: you should use batches only when you really need consistency, like, update 2 or 3 tables based on the common change factor. For all other cases it's better to issue every statement separately, or make sure that batch is against only single partition (in this case, it works the same as single change). In this case you'll remove an additional load to coordinating node because it won't need to write a batchlog.  To make things more reliable, you can mark queries as idempotent, and they will be automatically retried by driver.

Comment: I have one doubt. when you say "Logged & unlogged are not necessary correct terms - the correct term is single-partition vs multipartition batches". Logged and unlogged are the values of enum Type in com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement class. Are all multipartition batches need to be logged only?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't really matter - Cassandra will change the type anyway if it detects that it's multipartition.  As I wrote, doing async queries will solve your problems

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9283 for details about unlogged batches

Comment: I totally understand doing async queries will solve my problem. But still, I am wondering, if I have 5000 or 10000 or even more queries, will it not going to create any kind of issue?

Comment: It will create less load than one huge batch because queries will be spread between nodes, there will be no backup done, etc. Of course if you can batch multiple statements to one partition into one batch it would be more performant... here is example of different behavior of multi partition and single partition batches: https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TestBatches.java

Comment: And batch anyway is converted into individual statements, but on coordinator node

Comment: Hi @Alex Ott, thanks for patiently replying to my queries. I was going through DataStax documentation, I found "If multiple partitions are involved, batches are logged by default." and " Single partition batch operations are unlogged by default". so calling Batchstatement constructor with Type like new BatchStatement(Type batchType), cause any effect?

Comment: It doesn't cause significant effect, but for example, if you're using Unlogged with multiple partitions, then it will lead to generation of warnings on the server side